# Reading a signed char as unsigned - Type Promotion

Tags: c, char, int, type-conversion, integer-promotion

Consider this little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c = 0xFF;
    printf("%d\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is `-1`, as expected (considering `char` is signed in my
system). What I'm trying to do is to make it print `255`. This is of
course a simplification of the real situation, where I can't just define
`c` as unsigned.

The first possible change would be using `%u` as formatter instead, but
the usual type promotion rules apply here, and the number is printed as
2<sup>32</sup> - 1.

So is there any way to read the signed char as unsigned *before* it gets
promoted to an int? I could create a pointer to a unsigned char set to the
address of `c`, and dereference it later, but not sure if this is the best
approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c` is being promoted using signed promotion rules. Cast `c` to unsigned to use unsigned promotion.

```
printf("%u\n", (unsigned char)c);
```

Unsigned char will be promoted to unsigned int.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use %d instead of %u if you want to.

Comment: In this situation it is ok, because the value must be [0 - 256). Generally speaking, the specifier should match the variable type. I think GCC will complain if certain warnings are switched on.

Comment: Actually I tried casting as `(unsigned int)c` and this won't work (now I'm wondering why exactly). I hadn't tried with `(unsigned char)c`.

Comment: Ah, I guess the compiler sign extends when casting from signed char -> unsigned int. This way signed char -> unsigned int -> signed int returns the same value you started with.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, maybe the char first becomes an int (extending the sign) to then be read as unsigned. Why exactly your "_format specifier is not technically correct either_"? :-)

Comment: I should probably use `h` (is `hh` defined in C99?) to indicate its width. However, since type promotion with varargs is guaranteed by the standard, I actually don't see the  purpose of `h`. (`l` is necessary however!)